# Route IIS request to parent folder resource

Tags: asp.net, iis, path, virtual-directory

I would like to create an asp.net page in my site within a particular folder e.g. at www.xyz.com/go/mypage.aspx.  I would then like any requests that are routed to sub-folders of /go to actually route the request to this page.  i.e. a request to www.xyz.com/go/test/123 should actually end up being handled by /go/mypage.aspx. (Indeed, it is important that /go/test/123 does not actually have to exist - it won't).  Within the page I would then analyse the original path (/go/test/123) because it will contain embedded meaning.  In this way I can issue any number of urls to users, but all requests will end up at mypage.aspx.  The reason I am doing this is so I can issue personalised urls that look good but always arrive at the same page, which can then deal with the request accordingly.  I do not want the sub-folders to have to exist.  Ideally the users would also not have to specify a particular aspx page, but would just enter a url that has the necessary codes within it.  In essence I would like to replace querystring parameters with 'virtual' directory paths where the paths don't actually exist in IIS.

An example url that I would send would be www.xyz.com/go/geneva/2010/welcome/t5RT4W - I would then extract the info of geneva, 2010, welcome and t5RT4W in mypage.aspx which will receive control even though it lives at www.xyz.com/go/mypage.aspx.

Comment: You've got two options AFAIK: URL rewriting, either as an ISAPI plugin or I think you can do this in an filter, to map your url to mypage.aspx?city=geneva etc., or you can use the built-in routing support in ASP.NET 3.5+, and/or smash in some ASP.NET MVC pages which use this model. Which version of ASP.NET are you using? If you're just starting out on the project I'd suggest you start with ASP.NET MVC rather than ASP.NET forms.

Comment: Unfortunately it is an existing site using ASP 2.0